# EditText change size if I press enter or close the keyboard

Tags: java, android, layout, android-edittext

If I write numbers in my EditText the size doesn't change [Pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCrcz.png), but if i press enter or close the keyboard the EditText change size. [Pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYG0p.png)
Is it possible to turn it off? (All TableRows and EditTexts are the same just the column is diffrent)

```
    ...
<TableLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:padding="6dp"
      android:stretchColumns="*">

  <TableRow
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">
       <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:background="@drawable/background"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLength="3"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium" />
               ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set BOTH android:layout_width="0dp" and android:layout_weight="1" for each view within a table layout